# Ace Editor Emmet extension does not work with Liquid

Tags: liquid, ace-editor, emmet

I'm trying to get [Emmet](http://emmet.io) (as an [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io) extension) to work within Liquid template. I need Emmet to treat Liquid lang as HTML since there is no difference if we're talking about tag expand abbreviation.

Here is my current setup for Ace (all required JS files are loaded properly):

```
var template = ace.edit('ace-template');
template.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/liquid');
var Emmet = require('ace/ext/emmet');
Emmet.setCore(window.emmet);
template.setOption("enableEmmet", true);
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at that line:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ext/emmet.js#L391

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I just need to change `$modeId` like this: **template.session.$modeId = 'ace/mode/html';**

Comment: Link not working anymore